# How to add home-manager to my configuration.nix?

Tags: linux, nixos, nix

I want to add the `home-manager` channel to my `configuration.nix`, then install home-manager

**I don't have experience with NixOS**. A simple code snippet is much appreciated, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [good article](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Home_Manager) about that in the NixOs Wiki. Basically, you need to import two things in your `configuration.nix`:

- The resources from the home-manager's GitHub repository
- Your own `home.nix` config (see the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager#usage) for examples)

```
imports = [
    ...
    (import "${builtins.fetchTarball https://github.com/rycee/home-manager/archive/master.tar.gz}/nixos")
    /path/to/home.nix
  ];
```

You might also need to add `home-manager` to your list of packages to be installed.